# Toggle Disabled Attribute on Input Based on Checkbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a checkbox that is unchecked by default and a disabled input by default.

```
<label class="checkbox span3"><input type="checkbox"> I am a full-time student.</label>
<input class="inputIcon span3" id="disabledInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter School Name" disabled>
```

I have full control over the class and id names and the site uses jQuery so can use that or plain javascript if needed.

If a user checks the box, then the "disabled" attribute should be removed from the following input. If the user unchecks it should become disabled again.

Found a several similar questions on StackOverflow but none seem to be this exact use case.

Comment: Did you try modifying any of those solutions?

Comment: Yup. With no luck which is why I'm posting here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to assign id to checkbox to bind the click to particular checkbox,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vwsvE/2/)**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk">

$("#chk").click(function(){   
    $("#disabledInput").attr('disabled', !this.checked)
});
```

Comment: This option seems the cleanest. Trying it out now.

Comment: noticed function was mispelled, after fixing that, this works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @heavymark, so nice of you.

Comment: One last question. If the input did not have "disabled" by default and I wanted checking the box to add "disabled" and unchecking to remove it (so the opposite of my example above), is there any quick change for that to the code? IF not, no worries!

Comment: @heavymark, There is no change in this code whether your input is disabled or enabled by default

Comment: You may need this, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vwsvE/2/

Answer (score 2):

First give your checkbox an id

```
<input id='cbFullTime' type="checkbox">
```

Then in its click handler, fetch the textbox, and set its disabled **property** to the inverse of the current value of the checkbox's `checked` **property**:

```
$('#cbFullTime').click(function() { 
    var cbIsChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('#disabledInput').prop('disabled', !cbIsChecked); 
});
```

---

Note that, while using `attr` and `removeAttr` will work (assuming you're not using exactly jQuery 1.6), using the `prop` function is a bit simpler, and a bit more correct.  For more information, check out [this link](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
$(".checkbox").find("checkbox").click(function() { 
$('#disabledInput').prop('disabled', $(this).prop('checked')); 
});
```